# I need to breakout the date in SQL Server - date as column

Tags: sql-server

Dates:

```
3/25/2017
3/12-3/18
3/19-3/25
```

I have used this SQL statement:

```
Select  
    SUBSTRING ('3/12-3/18' , 1 , CHARINDEX('-','3/12-3/18') -1) + '/' + Convert(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy,Getdate())) as StartDate,
    SUBSTRING ('3/12-3/18' , CHARINDEX('-','3/12-3/18') + 1 , len('3/12-3/18')) + '/' + Convert(varchar, DATEPART(yyyy,Getdate())) as EndDate
```

but I'm unable to convert first one

Answer (score 1):

You really should store your dates as dates, and not strings.

Using a combination of `isnull()`, `nullif()`, and `datename()` to produce strings that can be `convert()`ed (in the `MDY` format anyway):

```
create table t ([date] varchar(32));
insert into t values ('3/25/2017'),('3/12-3/18'),('3/19-3/25');

select 
    startdate = convert(date,isnull(
        left(t.date,nullif(charindex('-',t.date)-1,-1))+'/'+datename(year,getdate())
      , t.date))
  , enddate   = convert(date,isnull(
        right(t.date,len(t.date)-nullif(charindex('-',t.date),0))+'/'+datename(year,getdate())
      , t.date))
from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WFO41395

returns:

```
+------------+------------+
| startdate  |  enddate   |
+------------+------------+
| 2017-03-25 | 2017-03-25 |
| 2017-03-12 | 2017-03-18 |
| 2017-03-19 | 2017-03-25 |
+------------+------------+
```